# Spark - Improve search time for string matching between list of names and zipped files

Tags: python, apache-spark, join, search, apache-spark-2.0

I'm trying to search for a list of strings in a list of zipped files using Spark.Below is the working code i use. Have saved list of strings to a dictionary with int key. I'm building a comma separated list of matching int keys against each file in function fnMatch. Although the code works, it takes several hours to complete. What optimization is possible to reduce runtime?

```
#Function to extract zip files 
def zip_extract(x):
    in_memory_data = io.BytesIO(x[1])
    file_obj = zipfile.ZipFile(in_memory_data, "r")
    files = [i for i in file_obj.namelist()]
    return dict(zip(files, [file_obj.open(file).read() for file in files]))


def safeStr(obj):
    try: return str(obj)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return obj.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    except: return ""

#Function to match string list contained in dictionary dcust, one by one against file doctext
def fnMatch(doctext,dcust):
  retval=""
  for k in dcust:
     if dcust[k] in doctext:
        retval=retval+","+str(k)

  return retval


schema = StructType([StructField('fpath', StringType(), True),StructField('docText', StringType(), True)])
zips = sc.binaryFiles('hdfs://hp3/user/test/testhdfs/myzipfile.zip')  
files_data = zips.map(zip_extract)
files_data_flat = files_data.flatMap(lambda x: x.items())
files_data_flat_tfm = files_data_flat.map(lambda x: (safeStr(x[0]),safeStr(x[1])))
df = hc.createDataFrame(files_data_flat_tfm,schema)
df2 = df.withColumn("docLength", size_(col("docText"))  ) 


dfcust = hc.sql('select fullname from tbl_custfull').toPandas()
res=len(dfcust)
print "##################################################"+str(res)+"##############################"
dictcust = dfcust.to_dict().values()[0]
strmatches = udf(lambda x: fnMatch(x,dictcust), StringType())

df2 = df2.withColumn("strMatches", strmatches(col("docText"))  ) 

df2.createOrReplaceTempView ("df2")
dfres=hc.sql("SELECT fpath,docLength,strMatches FROM df2 WHERE length(strMatches) >0")
dfres.show(5)
```

I submit the spark job using

```
spark-submit \
--conf spark.executor.memory=20g \
--conf spark.executor.cores=5 \
--conf spark.executor.instances=139 \
--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=8g \
--files /etc/spark2/conf/hive-site.xml \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
myprogram.py
```

Is there something i should be avoiding doing here to improve performance? Tried changing executor memory and cores , but not much difference. The list has around 270K strings and there are 60k documents

Comment: could you use GZip rather than zip?

Comment: Thanks Salim..I will change format to gzip and try..

Answer (score 0):

zip extension is not splittable so it can't be parallelized at record level. If you can use gzip compression then the performance will improve tremendously. Additionally reading the whole file into memory hash map and then searching is unnecessary and unscalable for large files. If gzip compression is used then Spark can automatically uncompress and search for you. Here is an example in Scala.

```
  val spark : SparkSession = SparkSession.builder
    .appName("Test")
    .master("local[2]")
    .config("spark.ui.enabled",false)
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val test = spark.read.text("/Users/..../temp/test.txt.gz")
  test.filter(r => r.getAs[String]("value").contains("gzip")).show(false)
```

The input file is test.gzip containing

```
this is just testing
to see that this test is passing
gzip is a splittable format
test to see it runs in parallel
```

Result

```
zgip is a splittable format
```